# Magento 2.1.5 : Reviews REST API

Tags: api, rest-api, magento2.1.5

I looked for reviews REST API and I found this link:

```
http://www.ipragmatech.com/products/reviews-rest-api-magento/
```

I tried to add review via it using :

**POST** `http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/review/post?productId=46&nickname=myName&title=Test&detail=Msg&ratingValue=3`

and got the response `[true,"You submitted your review for moderation."]`

But when I try to retrieve the reviews Using:

**GET**   http://domain.com/rest/V1/review/reviews/46

I got response `[{"avg_rating_percent":"0","count":0,"reviews":[]}]`

Answer (score 1):

You have to approve the review in order to view it.

Goto Marketing > Reviews > Change your Review Status > Save Review.

[image]

Comment: @Jsaporo30 I am actually submitting answer to ask your how to submit different rating value. Ex: Quality, Price, Value (how many stars for each one)

Comment: This answer has no clear explanation of the examples (passes that need to follow for review validation, or a print screen where this can be done), this type of answer could be a comment on the question.

Comment: @St3phan my mistake :(